# How to run an exe on Visual Studio with queries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

I want to run an exe on Windows.

In this application, I need to do on Ubuntu:

```
./test_pcl -query chair.ply
```

On Windows with Visual Studio, how to proceed within the console Windows?

Comment: It's Visual Studio sorry

Comment: I needed to do test_pcl.exe -query chair.ply in running the command prompt in the administrator mode.